# php_http.dll not Found on Windows 10 Machine

Tags: php, extension

So, I'm pretty stumped on why PHP can not find the php_http.dll extension that I put in my ext folder. I am currently using PHP 7.2, and I am working locally and using PHP's built-in web server. I downloaded the http extension from its PECL page. I learned that I need to install propro.dll and raphf.dll as well because http.dll is dependent on them, so I put those two extensions in the ext folder. I also make sure to put those two extensions above the php_http.dll in my extension list. However, while PHP is able to load those two dependencies without a problem, it still won't load the http extension. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: What does the web server log say?

Answer (score 0):

It requires "icuuc64.dll", but php 7.3/7.4 is with "icuuc65.dll". You can download icu64 from here: https://github.com/unicode-org/icu/releases/tag/release-64-2, download "icu4c-64_2-Win32-MSVC2017.zip" or "icu4c-64_2-Win64-MSVC2017.zip" based on your php version, Extract all .dll from bin or bin64, put them under php directory, then php_http should works.